# how to put markers in map after filtering data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

i am working on google map marker project and i am single step away from it. everything is working fine on search google maps markers are working fine. now the problem here is that when i filter it should show on related markers inside the map. i am bit confuse how to do it. i am new with JavaScript and JSON and its my first project on it.

here is the the link of my project https://cdn.assetrepository.me/maps-test/

below i pasted my code

```
    var currentCode = 0;
function selectmarker(ele) {
    $(".dealer-item_details").animate({
        left: '-100%'
    }, 'fast');
    $(".dealer-item_details .dealer-info-name, .c_phone, .c_email, .c_direction, .c_distance").empty();

    //  $('.result-dealers-items .dealer-info-name').click(function () {
    // $this = ele; 
    var info_name = ele.text();
    var info_distance = ele.siblings('.distance-units').html();
    $(".c_distance").append(info_distance);
    $(".dealer-item_details .dealer-info-name").append(info_name);
    var info_phone = ele.siblings('.dealer-list-phone').html();
    $(".c_phone").append(info_phone);
    var info_email = ele.siblings('.search_email').html();
    $(".c_email").append(info_email);
     $(".timing").html(ele.siblings(".mytiming").html())

    var info_direction = ele.siblings('.search_direction').html();
    $(".c_direction").append(info_direction);
    $(".dealer-item_details").animate({
        left: '0%'
    }, 'fast');
    // });

}
function nextChar() {
    currentCode++;
    var character = String.fromCharCode(64 + currentCode);

    // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = character;
    return character
}

var image = 'https://cdn.assetrepository.me/map/icon-marker.png';

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.0000, 45.0000),
    panControl: true,
    panControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
    overviewMapControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

var clusterStyles = [{
    url: 'https://cdn.assetrepository.me/test/images/map_tag.png', //'https://en.nissan-saudiarabia.com/etc/designs/nissan/19.08.5.NISSAN-18/common-assets/img/map/dealer-marker-alpha-default.png',
    height: 80,
    width: 75,
    // anchor: [45, 45],
    textColor: '#fff',
    textSize: 20
}];

var mcOptions = {
    styles: clusterStyles
};

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], mcOptions);

var options = {
    types: [],
    componentRestrictions: {
        country: "sa"
    }
};

var markers = [];
var input = document.getElementById('showroom_search');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
var icon = {
                url: 'https://cdn.assetrepository.me/test/images/user-location.png', // url
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 50), // scaled size
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10), // anchor
                labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(20, 20)
            };

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29),
    icon: icon
});

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace()

    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        var value = place;
        console.log(geoLat)
    } else {
        console.log(place.geometry.location)
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }

    var geoLong = value.geometry.location.lng();
    var geoLat = value.geometry.location.lat();

    var point_a = new google.maps.LatLng(geoLong, geoLat);

    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    markerCluster.clearMarkers();
    markers = [];
    currentCode = 0;
    $('.result-dealers-items .dealer-item').remove();
    var searchField = $('#showroom_search').val();
    alert(searchField);        
    searchField = searchField.substr(searchField.lastIndexOf(",") + 1).trim()
    var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    var counter = 0;
              var week = ["MONDAY"
                    ,"TUESDAY"
                    ,"WEDNESDAY"
                    ,"THURSDAY"
                    ,"FRIDAY"
                    ,"SATURDAY"
                    ,"SUNDAY"]
    $.getJSON('https://cdn.assetrepository.me/json/Petromin_en.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
               var timing = ""
            if (value.city.search(expression) != -1 || value.city.search(expression) != -1) {

                var geoLong_a = value.longitude;
                var geoLat_s = value.latitude;

                var point_b = new google.maps.LatLng(geoLong_a, geoLat_s);
                // console.log(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point_a, point_b)/ 1000)
                var distancce = (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point_a, point_b) / 1000).toFixed(2);
                var servicelist = ""
                 for (ser in value.services_list){
                     servicelist += value.services_list[ser] + " | ";
                 }
                //if (distancce < 5.1) 
                {
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    var char = nextChar();
                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(geoLat_s, geoLong_a);
                    var icon = {
                        url: 'https://cdn.assetrepository.me/test/images/map_tag.png', // url
                        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 50), // scaled size
                        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
                        anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10), // anchor
                        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(20, 20)
                    };
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        label: {
                            text: char,
                            color: "white",
                            fontSize: "20",
                            fontWeight: "bold"
                        }, // labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],

                        'position': latLng,
                        icon: icon
                    });

                    html = "<div> test </div>";
                    makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, html, marker);

                   for (ser in value.services_list)
                       markers[value.services_list[ser]] = []

                    for (ser in value.services_list)
                       markers[value.services_list[ser]].push(marker)
                    display = "display:none"
                   for (ser in markers){   
                         console.log(markers)
                    // if($(".showroom_btn").parent("check_row").hasClass("active_check_btn")){
                        if(markers["Showroom Sales"]){
                         markerCluster.addMarkers(markers["Showroom Sales"]);
                         display = "display:block"
                        }

                     //}
                   }
                    function makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, contentString, marker) {
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                            console.log(marker.label.text)
                            selectmarker(
                                $('.indicator:contains(' + marker.label.text + ')').parent(".dealer-info").find(".dealer-info-name"));
                        });
                    }
                    for(ss in value.OpeningHours){
                    timing += '<tr>'
                                +'<td><strong>'+week[parseInt(ss)-1]+'</strong></td>'
                                +'<td>'+value.OpeningHours[ss].openFrom+' - '+value.OpeningHours[ss].openUntil+'</td>'
                            +'</tr>';
                    }
                    $('.result-dealers-items').append(
                        '<li class="dealer-item"><div class="indicator">' 
                        + char + 
                        '</div><div class="dealer-info"><h3 class="dealer-info-name">' +
                        value.name +
                        '<span class="statename"> &nbsp' +
                        value.state +
                        '</span></h3><p class="hide_search dealer-list-phone"><a href="tel:' + value.phones + '"> Call ' +
                        value.phones +
                        '</a></p><p class="distance-units hide_search">(' +
                        distancce +
                        " KM" +
                        ')</p><p class="hide_search search_email hide_main"><a href="email:' + value.email + '"> Email <span class="hide_text">' +
                        value.showroomemail +
                        '</span></a></p><p class="hide_search search_direction hide_main"><a href="' + "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/" + value.latitude + "," + value.longitude + '" target="_blank">Get Directions </a><span class="hide_text">' + "aaa"+
                        '</span><p class="serv_list">'+
                            servicelist
                        +'</p>'+
                        '<table style="display:none;" class="mytiming">  '+timing+' </table></li>'
                    );
                }
            }

              $(".reset_filter").click()  
        });
        $('.result-dealers-items .dealer-info-name').click(function() {
            selectmarker($(this))
        });
        $('.back_to').click(function() {
            $(".dealer-item_details").animate({
                left: '-100%'
            }, 'fast');
            $(".dealer-item_details .dealer-info-name, .c_phone, .c_email, .c_direction, .c_distance").empty();
        });
    });

});

var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="showroom_services"]');
[].forEach.call(cbs, function (cb) {
    cb.addEventListener("click", function(){
    const listSelected =  [...document.querySelectorAll( 'input[name="showroom_services"]:checked' )].map(ele=>ele.value);
        document.querySelectorAll('.dealer-item')
        .forEach(ele=>{ 
            if(listSelected.some(l=> ele.textContent.includes(l))){
                ele.classList.add("list_active");ele.classList.remove("list_deactive")
            }
            else if(listSelected.every(l=> ele.textContent.includes(l))){
                ele.classList.add("list_active");ele.classList.remove("list_deactive")
            }
            else {
                ele.classList.add("list_deactive");ele.classList.remove("list_active")
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to look at - can you pinpoint which part isn't working correctly?

Comment: in this code everything working fine i want to put marker when i filter something